# Typescript: Why would this generic merge fail?

Tags: typescript, types

Given these types in Typescript 2.5.3...

```
type Data<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]?: T[K]
}

interface Merge {
    body: {
        isMerged: boolean
    }
}

interface Args {
    one: number
    two: number
}
```

Why would this function fail to compile:

```
function merge<T>(data: Data<T>): Merge & { body: Data<T> } {
    const merged = {
        body: {
            isMerged: true
        }
    }

    // Written this way to guarantee { body: isMerged } remains intact
    merged.body = Object.assign({}, data, merged.body);

    return merged;
}
```

[image]

And yet this call...

```
const m = merge<Args>({
    one: 1,
    two: 2,
});
```

... correctly infers the returned data?

[image]

**Edit:**

I realise that explicitly casting the return type as:

```
return <Merge & { body: Data<T> }> merged;
```

... suppresses the error, but my question is why can't Typescript infer the type when:

- It knows the return type in the function signature
- It can see that no changes have been made to `data` in the body

**Edit 2 and conclusion/answer:**

Based on Titian Cernicova-Dragomir's answer, the TL;DR seems to be this: The type that's *initially* defined is the type assigned. **Types don't morph.**

I was expecting Typescript to know that adding additional keys to a type would allow it to ultimately satisfy the return type interface, but it seems that the type that's initially defined is the one that sticks.

Therefore, the function should be:

```
function merge<T>(data: Data<T>): Merge & { body: Data<T> } {
    const merged ={
        body : Object.assign({}, data, {
            isMerged: true
        })
    };
    return merged;
}
```

i.e. with `merged` defined in one expression, rather than added to over multiple expressions.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `const merged` is typed with the body that you set to it (an object with only the isMerged property) when you try to assign it to something that has a body of `{ isMerged: boolean } &  Data<T>` it will fail because there is no way to tell that the object will satisfy the `Data<T>` interface. Try:

```
function merge<T>(data: Data<T>): Merge & { body: Data<T> } {
    const merged ={
        body : Object.assign({}, data, {
            isMerged: true
        })
    };
    return merged;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not getting why `merged = {body: Object.assign({}, data, { isMerged: true })};` and `merged = {body: { isMerged: true }}; merged.body = Object.assign({}, data, merged.body);` are functionally different. Are you saying that a merged constant gets the type it's _first_ defined with - even if part of the object is later updated to conform to the return shape?

Comment: Yes, when you declare and assign a variable, the type of the variable is decided by the assignment unless you specify a type annotation explicitly.

Comment: In this case, if you would have declared `const merged : Merge & { body: Data<T> } `  you still would have had an error when trying to do the initialization, because `{ isMerged: true }` does not satisfy the `Data<T>` interface.

Comment: I get that `Merge & { body: Data<T> }` wouldn't be satisfied at the point of declaration if `data` hadn't yet been applied; my question is more as to whether Typescript is savvy enough to handle _morphing types_ or whether the original type contract is set in stone. I guess it's the latter. Thanks for enlightening me.